# Install Circuit Maker (Elementary OS)

Tags: elementary-os

is there a way to install circuit maker on linux distribution? Google-ed it hardly find any luck.

Comment: Googling "install circuit maker on linux" brings a lot of hits, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Circuit Maker is Windows software. You either can run it via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/) as described in more detail [here](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/cm/cmlinux.htm).

If you're have other windows applications that your (have to) run every once in a while, you might want to install virtual machine manager, create an appropriate Windows VM (license required) and install Circuit Maker in there. Doing that with VirtualBox and Windows XP works.